# how get value from Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am new in android and I want to get `userIDS` from Firebase Database, I've tried by using this but it returns `null`.

- By using this code
- Value of `Constants.ARG_CHAT_GROUP_ROOMS`=`Groups` and `Constants.NEW_NODE`=`newGroup`

---

```
    private void getMYuid() {
    String senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DatabaseReference mTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    mTest.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_GROUP_ROOMS).child(Constants.NEW_NODE)
            .child(senderUid).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
            Toast.makeText(ActivityChatView.this, "not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Log.e("151","ACV"+dataSnapshot);
        }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    Log.e("139","ACV"+senderUid);
    }
```

---

- Database Structure is this

---

### [image]

Comment: What are the values of `Constants.ARG_CHAT_GROUP_ROOMS` and `Constants.NEW_NODE`?

Comment: `Constant.ARG_CHAT_GROUP_ROOMS` = `Groups` and
`Constants.NEW_NODE` = `newGroup`

Comment: So you need the value of `from_uid` from `1505217176288_myGroupName_1`, correct?

Comment: nopes its  `userIDS`  and it is in `array`

Comment: Between `Groups` and `newGroup` there's another child node you're missing.

Comment: yes, there is another child but problem is that  it is a combination of timestamp,myGroupName is `static` and other text filled by user

Comment: Laert's answer shows why your current code doesn't work: you're listening for a non-existing node.  Aside from that it is unclear what you're trying to accomplish; what you shared seems like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please update your question to describe what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you want the first one under 15052169227329_myGroupName_Hell By Anne: Your problem is that you forgot the node before "Constants.NEW_NODE"

```
private void getMYuid() {
        String senderUid = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        DatabaseReference mTest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        mTest.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_GROUP_ROOMS).child("15052169227329_myGroupName_Hell By Anne").child(Constants.NEW_NODE)
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    Toast.makeText(ActivityChatView.this, "not exist", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Log.e("151","ACV"+dataSnapshot);
                }

                // You can cast this object later but it seems that that is a string and not an array
                Object yourRequiredObject = dataSnapshot.child("usersIDS").getValue();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        Log.e("139","ACV"+senderUid);
    }
```

Comment: @Laret it not a static value `15052169227329_myGroupName_Hell By Anne`  its combination of timestamp_mygroupName(is static)_value entered by user

Comment: @VishalYadav I just made an example with the first one to show you what you were missing in the code, which is one node. That is the case when you want to get the userIDS of only 1 newgroup object.

Comment: on what basis we can get this value i dont know

Comment: @VishalYadav sorry I did not understand you. Do you have the second node (15052169227329_myGroupName_Hell By Anne  or  others like this) stored somewhere? If you are going to access a specific element under this node you need to have it stored somewhere so you can use .child(your node name). You can always use `Test.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_GROUP_ROOMS)` and then iterate through it with `dataSnapshot.getChildren().iterator().next();` but this is not a solution to your problem

Answer (score 1):

As i see, it's not an array it's a String. To get the `userIDS`, please use the following code:

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
DatabaseReference yourRef = rootRef.child(Constants.ARG_CHAT_GROUP_ROOMS).child(senderUid).child(Constants.NEW_NODE);
ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        String usersIDS = dataSnapshot.child("usersIDS").getValue(String.class);
        Log.d("TAG", usersIDS);
        //Here you can split the usersIDS String by , (comma)
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
};
yourRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);
```

In which `senderUid` is the missing child. This child can have the value like `1505217176288_myGroupName_1` or other coresponding group names.

Comment: thanks for your answer but it still gives me `null` value not work

Comment: What is the value of `senderUid`?

Comment: `tKyhXXAf6TQnQgKyAf23RJcwhsn1` it is, I want to perform operation
if this value is present in any group then the message would be received by group's user

Comment: That's the reason is null because i thought that senderUid is 1505217176288_myGroupName_1. What is the name of the variable that holds this concatenated String `1505217176288_myGroupName_1`?

Comment: `1505217176288_myGroupName_1` its combination of timestamp_myGroupName(is static)_this value is enter by the  user

Comment: So to solve this, you need to use this combination of timestamp_myGroupName inside the declaration of `DatabaseReference`. So you need to change that `senderUid` with this combination. Ok?